# Trying to get Sum of all method

Tags: c#

I am trying to get sum of all method that has been passed in.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Add(2, 2);
    Add(5, 2);
    Add(2, 5);
}

public static void Add(int num1, int num2)
{
    int sum = num1 + num2;

    Print(sum);
}

public static void Print(int total) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(total);    //The total would be 4,7,7 
                                 //But i want the total to be 18 (4+7+7).
}
```

Comment: You are printing the sum of the arguments of the add function each time you call it. What you need to make sum a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Return a result of `Add` method and calculate sum of results of all `Add` methods

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var results = new[]
    {
        Add(2, 2),
        Add(5, 2),
        Add(2, 5)
    };

    Print(results);
}

// Change signature to return a result
public static int Add(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}

public static void Print(params int[] values) 
{
    var total = values.Sum();
    var results = string.Join(" + ", values);
    var output = $"{total} ({results})"

    Console.WriteLine(output);    // => 18 (4 + 7 + 7).
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i been looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Change the code like following

```
private static int sum = 0;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Add(2,2);
    Add(5, 2);
    Add(2, 5);
}

public static void Add(int num1,int num2)
{
    sum += num1 + num2;

    Print(sum);
}
public static void Print(int total) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(total);    //This will print 4,11,18 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to move the sum variable to the outer scope. Code should look like this:

```
private static int sum=0;    
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Add(2,2);
        Add(5, 2);
        Add(2, 5);
    }
    
    public static  void Add(int num1,int num2)
    {
        sum += num1 + num2;
    
        Print(sum);
    }
    
    public static void Print(int total) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(total);      
    }
```